# Hidden the iOS' Default.png only when tap on screen

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad

Consider using the `Default.png` as the app splash image, it is possible to control the app to hide the Default.png **only** when user interact with the app,

e.g. tap on screen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add your default.png as a UIImageView in `applicationDidFinishLaunching:WithOptions:`, then add a UITapGestureRecognizer to it wired up to your dismissal code.

Answer (score 0):

You can display an UIImageView with the exact image, attach an UIGestureRecognizer and let it handle the tap.